# Performance of multiplying two identity matrices

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, sparse-arrays

I am running Mathematica 13.3.1.0 on a M1 Mac, and I ran the following codes to check on the time spent on matrix multiplication.

```
d = 1000000;
one = IdentityMatrix[d];
sparse = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} :> 1}, d]

(one.one // Timing)[[1]]
(sparse . sparse // Timing)[[1]]
```

In actual trials, when `d` is small like `d = 100, 1000`, the `one.one` takes much **longer** time (~`0,00x, 0.0x`) to run than the `SparseArray` code (`<0,0000x`).

However, when `d = 10000` and `100000`, the `one.one` actually runs a lot **faster** (~`0.0000x`), while the `SparseArray` takes about `0.000x, 0.00x` to run.

I wonder what causes the improvement of the `one.one` performance as `d` goes up to `10000`? And what is the general performance suggestion regarding large matrix multiplication, e.g., usual matrix against `SparseArray`?

Comment: Note that in 13.3, `IdentityMatrix[d]` gives a structured array automatically for `d >= 10^4`, which is optimized for fast computations. Look at the `TargetStructure` option as well.